# Generate Sparse Vector from dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, sparse-matrix

I have one DF with users list:

```
+-------+---+
|   user| Id|
+-------+---+
|  Peter|  1|
|    Max|  2|
|  Steve|  3|
|  Chris|  4|
```

and have another DF with information what page visited which user:

```
+-----------+-------+
|       page|   user|
+-----------+-------+
|      Page1|  Peter|
|      Page1|    Max|
|      Page2|    Max|
|      Page3|  Steve|
|      Page3|  Chris|
|      Page4|  Chris|
```

I did a "inner" join by **user** field:

```
+-----------+-------+---+
|       page|   user| Id|
+-----------+-------+---+
|      Page1|  Peter|  1| 
|      Page1|    Max|  2| 
|      Page2|    Max|  2| 
|      Page3|  Steve|  3| 
|      Page3|  Chris|  4| 
|      Page4|  Chris|  4|
```

now want to create Sparse Vector of this DF which will look like this:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|   page|                                            features|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  Page1|SparseVector({Peter: 1.0, Max: 1.0, Steve: 0.0,...})|
|  Page2|SparseVector({Peter: 0.0, Max: 1.0, Steve: 0.0,...})|
|  Page3|SparseVector({Peter: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Steve: 1.0,...})|
|  Page4|SparseVector({Peter: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Steve: 0.0,...})|
```

where will be set a "1.0" if there is a user for the page and "0.0" if user not present for the page

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinHashLSH
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")

df = sc.parallelize([Row(PAGE="Page1", USER="Peter", USER_ID=1),
                     Row(PAGE="Page1", USER="Max", USER_ID=2),
                     Row(PAGE="Page2", USER="Max", USER_ID=2),
                     Row(PAGE="Page3", USER="Steve", USER_ID=3),
                     Row(PAGE="Page3", USER="Chris", USER_ID=4),
                     Row(PAGE="Page4", USER="Chris", USER_ID=4)]).toDF()


dfpivot=(df.groupBy("PAGE").pivot("USER").count().na.fill(0))
dfpivot.show()
input_cols = [x for x in dfpivot.columns if x != "PAGE"]


dfassembler1 = (VectorAssembler(inputCols=input_cols, outputCol="features").transform(dfpivot)
                .select("PAGE", "features"))
dfassembler1.show()

mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", numHashTables=3)
model = mh.fit(dfassembler1)

model.transform(dfassembler1).show(3, False)
```

but I'm getting some exception: cannot resolve column name ... and error while calling "transform"

may be I'm doing something wrong. I'd appreciate for any help

Comment: your code is working fine when i run it. Can you include all imports and other parts as well?

Comment: included imports

Comment: Can you include the full error trace?

Comment: `
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'The pivot column author has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues to at least the number of distinct values of the pivot column.;'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message. Just set `spark.sql.pivotMaxValues` in configuration to the number of distinct values you are expecting.

```
set('spark.sql.pivotMaxValues', '999999')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked for me

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", 9000000)
```